# Ajax two buttons one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, list, select

I'm using this code >>>

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function showUser(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <button type="button" value="Baseball" onclick="showCustomer(this.value)">1</button>

        <button type="button" value="Futbol" onclick="showCustomer(this.value)">2</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>

</html>
```

my question is I can use same function on two different buttons?
but I will not change the result when i clic button1

explain

when i click button1:

here display list  players of futbol

```
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="">BLUE</option>
```

when i clic button2:
here display list of  baseball

```
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
```

These two lists are independent
when I click the button one list is loaded 
but when I click the button two the first list disappears.
I can use the same function to two buttons, which result in separate lists?

Comment: just pass an additional parameter to your function `showCustomer(this.value, 1)` for button 1 and 2 for button 2

Comment: the content is changing in the two select is the same , Can u explain more precisely

Comment: can i see your `ShowCustomer()` method?